# Set header for a file with a rewrite-if-not-file rule

Tags: lighttpd

We are using lighttpd as a webserver for static files.
I have to add a header to all requests that serve the file *index.$SYSTEM_ENV.html*.
There is also a *rewrite-if-not-file* rule that complicates all things:

```
# Return index.html when the requested file does not exist.
url.rewrite-if-not-file = ("/(.*)" => "/index." + env.SYSTEM_ENV + ".html")
```

I would like to add the header to all requests that serve the file "/index." + env.SYSTEM_ENV + ".html".

How can I do that? The header should only be added if the file index.$SYSTEM_ENV.html was served. *.js and *.css do not need this header. Is there a way to add a rule for the physical file instead of the path of the request?

Currently, we add this header to all files:

```
# Set security headers
$HTTP["url"] =~ "/.*" {
    setenv.add-response-header += ("X-Frame-Options" => "DENY")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[lighttpd mod_rewrite](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModRewrite) re-runs the configuration after a URL is rewritten internally.

Did you try the following?

```
var.index_system_env = "/index." + env.SYSTEM_ENV + ".html"
$HTTP["url"] == var.index_system_env {
    setenv.add-response-header += ("X-Frame-Options" => "DENY")
}
```

If the above does not meet your needs then you can look at using [lighttpd mod_magnet](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModMagnet) with `magnet.attract-response-start-to = ("/path/to/your/lua.script")` and write a simple Lua script to set the response header as needed.

```
server.modules += ("mod_magnet", "mod_setenv")
magnet.attract-response-start-to = ("/path/to/system_env_index.lua")
var.index_system_env = "/index." + env.SYSTEM_ENV + ".html"
setenv.set-environment += ("SYSTEM_ENV" => env.SYSTEM_ENV)
$HTTP["url"] == var.index_system_env {
    setenv.add-response-header += ("X-Frame-Options" => "DENY")
}
```

/path/to/system_env_index.lua

```
local r = lighty.r
-- if r.req_attr["response.http-status"] == "404" then   -- lighttpd <1.4.65
if r.req_item.http_status == 404 then                    -- lighttpd 1.4.65+
  local target = r.req_attr["physical.doc-root"] ..
                 '/index.' .. r.req_env["SYSTEM_ENV"] .. '.html'
  local st = lighty.c.stat(target)
  if st then
    r.resp_header["X-Frame-Options"] = "DENY"
    r.resp_body.set()
    return st["http-response-send-file"]
  end
end
```

I do not know how or why you are using SYSTEM_ENV, but the above would be simpler without it.

Comment: Thx a lot. It seems to work for url.rewrite-once but not for url.rewrite-if-not-file.

Comment: I see that, too.  Unfortunately, that is a limitation in the current mod_setenv.  lighttpd mod_setenv tries to avoid repeatedly adding headers when the request is restarted, so it does not reconfigure for the new url after the `url.rewrite-if-not-file`.  (`url.rewrite-once` applies very early in the request, before mod_setenv is configured for the request.)